# AHK don't consume input?

Tags: autohotkey

I have another program listening to `ctrl alt shift numpaddiv`; but autohotkey consumes the input. How can I tell autohotkey to not consume it?

```
^!+NumPadDiv::
    Run, log_base_timestamp.py ,,Hide
return
```

Comment: You could repeat the input instead

Comment: I'd rather not if I don't have to, just to keep the code a little more dry. But hey `Send, ^!+{NumPadDiv}` does work. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if it will work here, but normally when you add ~ in front of the hotkey, that hotkey will be passed on to the OS instead of blocking it. In your situation it would be:

```
~^!+NumPadDiv::
    Run, log_base_timestamp.py ,,Hide
return
```